# Viewing a Deleted File in Git

Tags: git

I've deleted a file with Git and then committed, so the file is no longer in my working copy. I want to look at the contents of that file, but not actually restore it. How can I do this?

Answer (score 173, accepted):

```
git show HEAD^:path/to/file
```

You can use an explicit commit identifier or `HEAD~n` to see older versions or if there has been more than one commit since you deleted it.

Comment: Note that `path/to/file` is full path from the top of project (top dir of repository).

Comment: I've got `fatal: Invalid object name 'HEAD^'.` (I have to mention, that I have only "Initial commit")

Comment: If the deletion is staged but not committed, use HEAD instead of HEAD^ (since it existed in HEAD). For instance, I thought I needed  file, so I added it and committed to save my work, then later deleted it when I came up with a different solution. To see the original file before committing again, I did git show HEAD:path/to/file

Comment: I think it's also worth mentioning that this only works if the file was deleted in the most recent commit.  If the file was deleted several commits ago, you'll need to use one of the other answers.

Answer (score 70):

If this is a file you've deleted a while back and **don't want to hunt for a revision**, you can use (the file is named `foo` in this example; you can use a full path):

```
git show $(git rev-list --max-count=1 --all -- foo)^:foo
```

The `rev-list` invocation looks for all the revisions of `foo` but only lists one. Since `rev-list` lists in reverse chronological order, then what it lists is the last revision that changed `foo`, which would be the commit that deleted `foo`. (This is based on the assumption that git does not allow a deleted file to be changed and yet *remain* deleted.) You cannot just use the revision that `rev-list` returns **as-is** because `foo` no longer exists there. You have to ask for the one just before it which contains the last revision of the file, hence the `^` in `git show`.

Comment: You might need to change the last foo to ./foo. And for them not using bash, get the id with "git rev-list --max-count=1 --all -- foo" and then do "git show 5824127a8d99576632a04ac2b5c2344bcf751967:./foo" with the id (524.. is the id)

Comment: Nice answer.  I had to use ~ instead of ^.  Not sure why.  And just so people are clear on it, 'foo' here must be a full path from the git root.

Comment: You can write `**/foo` if you don't know the path (this will work for the rev-list command but not the show command. However with the commit from the rev-list command you can then find the path).

Comment: As of the date of this comment, using `^` does not work with `git show` or `git log`.
Had to use `git log -p` with `~` to get this to work.

Answer (score 11):

Since you might not recall the exact path, you can instead get the sha1 from git log then you can simply issue

```
 git cat-file -p <sha1>
```

Comment: On behalf of [Samuel Slund](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/2993006): One way to find the sha1 sum to use above is: `git whatchanged --no-abbrev` that gives output similar to git (or svn) log.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a way to find a file that was deleted long ago, even if you don't remember the *exact* name and/or path:

`git log --stat=1000 --full-history -- "**/*partial_file_name*.*"`

- `--stat=1000` lists all the files in the commits. The `1000` ensures you'll see **the entire relative path** to the deleted file (https://stackoverflow.com/a/10460154/99717)
- `--full-history` shows the reverse commit history for the file, starting with the delete commit.

This way, you can also search for a specific file version in a specific commit by scanning the messages and history.

With the commit hash, you can view the file using:

`git show COMMIT_HASH:entire/relative/path/to/deleted_file_name.ext`

Getting the relative path right is important, else git will tell you it can't find that path. Also, you have to use a commit hash *before* the actual file delete commit, which will have nothing, because `git show` shows you the version of the file *in that commit*.