# Making git diff --stat show full file path

Tags: git, git-diff

On doing `git diff --stat` some files are listed with full path from repository base but some files are listed as:

```
.../short/path/to/filename.
```

That is the path starts with `...` and only short path is shown.

I would like `git diff` to list full file path for all files for it to be easily processed by a script. Is there some way I can get `git diff` to always show full path

Answer (score 157, accepted):

By default `git diff` truncates its output to fit into a 80-column terminal.

You can override this by specifying values using the [`--stat` option](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff#Documentation/git-diff.txt---statltwidthgtltname-widthgtltcountgt):

```
--stat[=<width>[,<name-width>[,<count>]]]
       Generate a diffstat. You can override the default output width for
       80-column terminal by --stat=<width>. The width of the filename
       part can be controlled by giving another width to it separated by a
       comma. By giving a third parameter <count>, you can limit the
       output to the first <count> lines, followed by ...  if there are
       more.

       These parameters can also be set individually with
       --stat-width=<width>, --stat-name-width=<name-width> and
       --stat-count=<count>.
```

For example, by setting the output value to a very large number:

```
git diff --stat=10000
```

Note that produces the path relative to the root of the git repository.

(For scripting you might want to use `git diff-tree` directly since it's more of a "plumbing" command, although I suspect you'll be fine either way.  Note that you need the same extra text with `--stat` when using `git diff-tree`.  The essential difference between using the `git diff` "porcelain" front end, and the `git diff-tree` plumbing command, is that `git diff` looks up your configured settings for options like `diff.renames` to decide whether to do rename detection.  Well, that, plus the front end `git diff` will do the equivalent of `git diff-index` if you're comparing a commit with the index, for instance.  In other words, `git diff` *reads your config* and *invokes the right plumbing automatically*.)

Comment: git diff --numstat is the same as diff-tree

Comment: Note that to limit the width of the last part (+++/---) you can use a separate `--stat-graph-width=...` switch. Note also that setting high `--stat-graph-width=` and `--stat-name-width=` is not enough, you must also set `--stat-width=` big enough to cover the two.

Comment: @jakub.g: good point.  Based on a bit of digging in the git source, this went in with git 1.7.10.

Comment: Is there any way to globalize this? Typing it every time is crazy.

Comment: @Rudie: alas, no: there's a configuration variable `diff.statGraphWidth` you can use to set the `--stat-graph-width` value, but the others default to your terminal width.  (So, alternative answer: "yes, just make your terminal window 1000 columns wide" :-) )

Comment: @torek I tried to make a git alias or bash script to `git diff --stat=$COLUMNS,$COLUMNS ...` but they both don't know `$COLUMNS` =( Works perfectly directly on commandline, but I'm not typing all that! =)

Comment: You'd have to set `COLUMNS` in your environment.  An alias or script could then use `${COLUMNS+--stat=$COLUMNS...}` to check whether it's set and if so, pass it on (or explicitly test it for nonzero length first, or whatever).

Comment: `git diff-tree` is more suited for scripting. But don't use `--stat`, there are better options. See my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/67330880/1507124

Comment: `git diff-tree` doesn’t support `--no-index` like `git diff` does :/

Comment: @bfontaine: Yes: `git diff-tree` always compares two existing tree objects inside the repository. That is, it cannot look *outside* the repository at all, nor can it look at the index, so `--no-index` is not available here. It's a bit of a problem since there's no `--porcelain` option to `git diff` though! The workaround, if you really need one, is to create a tree object from some directory in the file system (using a temporary index and `git write-tree`).

Answer (score 34):

For script processing, it might be better to use one of the following:

```bash
# list just the file names
git diff --name-only
path/to/modified/file
path/to/renamed/file


# list the names and change statuses:
git diff --name-status
M       path/to/modified/file
R100    path/to/existing/file   path/to/renamed/file


# list a diffstat-like output (+ed lines, -ed lines, file name):
git diff --numstat
1       0       path/to/modified/file
0       0       path/to/{existing => renamed}/file
```

These each become more handy for robust script processing when combined with the `-z` option, which uses `NUL` as the field terminators.

Comment: According to my tests you do not receive the full path of the resource using these commands.
For now I only see relative paths for deleted files. I don't know if this is only the case for these files.

Comment: All outpu will return paths relative to `git rev-parse --show-toplevel`. The original problem was referring to truncated paths, which is a problem in diffstats, particularly for long filenames or a low value for `--stat-name-width`. The commands above will not truncate the paths, but will show the "full" path as requested, albeit still relative to the repository root.

Answer (score 21):

For Bash users, you can use the `$COLUMNS` variable to automatically fill the available terminal width:

```
git diff --stat=$COLUMNS
```

Very long path names might still be truncated; in this case, you can reduce the width of the +++/--- part using `--stat-graph-width`, for example this limits it to 1/5 of the terminal width:

```sh
git show --stat=$COLUMNS --stat-graph-width=$(($COLUMNS/5))
```

For a more generic solution, you could use the output of `tput cols` to determine the terminal width.

Comment: Is there any way to globalize `--stat=$COLUMNS,$COLUMNS`? Typing it every time is crazy.

Comment: @Rudie add `export COLUMNS` to your `~/.bashrc`, and in your `~/.gitconfig` under `[alias]`, add `smart-diff = ! "gitsmartdiff() { git diff $2 --stat=$COLUMNS,$COLUMNS; }; gitsmartdiff"`

Comment: @user151841 That changes only `diff`. I want it to work for merges and pulls etc too. (Can't even manually do it there.) I don't think GIT supports it.

Comment: @Rudie  Well, after the pull or merge is complete, you can diff between the previous and the new hashes.

Comment: @user151841 Sure, but merging already gives a stat summary. Without parameters/config. It'd be great if all 'stat summaries' used the same config.

Comment: @Rudie I created an aliases that seems to do what you want. Check my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55796232/151841

Answer (score 8):

There’s an option `--name-only`: `git diff --name-only`. The option is also supported by other git commands like `show` and `stash`.

Paths don’t get shortened with the option.

Comment: There's also a corresponding option for `git diff-tree` but there are other options you need to specify like `git diff-tree --name-only -r --no-commit-id HEAD`. See my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/67330880/1507124 for more info

Answer (score 3):

A simple solution I found was to do this: (only works on *nix, sorry no osx)

```
git diff --stat=$COLUMNS --relative | head -n -1 | cut -c 2- | xargs -d '\n' -P4 printf "$(pwd)/%s\n"
```

This version works for both, but it doesn't look great on osx.

```
git diff --stat=$COLUMNS --relative | sed -e '$ d' | cut -c 2- | xargs -n4 -I{} echo "$(pwd)/{}"
```

Comment: I found that just using `--relative` helped me immensely.  (I already use the `--stat` width options.

Answer (score 3):

`git diff` is a porcelain (user friendly) command. For scripting purposes, you probably want to use the corresponding plumbing command `git diff-tree`.

You can get `git diff-tree` to output the full paths, relative to the git repository, using a combination of the [`--name-only`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff-tree#Documentation/git-diff-tree.txt---name-only), [`-r`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff-tree#Documentation/git-diff-tree.txt--r) and [`--no-commit-id`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff-tree#Documentation/git-diff-tree.txt---no-commit-id) options.

### Examples

Paths of files changed in the "last" (the `HEAD`) commit of the current branch.

```sh
git diff-tree --name-only -r --no-commit-id HEAD
```

Paths of files in the last commit on the `main` branch

```sh
git diff-tree --name-only -r --no-commit-id main
```

Paths of files of the last three commits on the `main` branch

```sh
git diff-tree --name-only -r main main~3
```

Paths of the files of the last commit under path `src/`

```sh
git diff-tree --name-only -r --no-commit-id main src/
```

Absolute paths of the files changed in the last commit on the current branch

```sh
git diff-tree --name-only -r --no-commit-id --line-prefix=`git rev-parse --show-toplevel`/ HEAD
```

### Explanation

`git diff-tree` compares the *blobs* of two *treeish* objects.

A commit is a `treeish` object, which points to the objects in the repository root. Directories are also `treeish` objects whereas files are `blobs`.

Running `git diff-tree HEAD` will compare the blobs of `HEAD` and `HEAD~1` and contain the difference in blobs of the repository root. To see all the changed files that are not in the root, we need to descend into the directory `treeish` objects. This is achieved using the `-r` (as in recurse) option.

Note that this allows one two compare arbitrary directories in arbitrary commits.

By default, if only one *commit* object is specified, it's compared to its parent. Ie, running `git diff-tree HEAD` is equivalent to `git diff-tree HEAD HEAD~1`. If you only specified one commit as the *treeish* object, the parent commit id is displayed. Using `--no-commit-id` gets rid of this.

`git-diff-tree` prints a lot of information we don't want (ids, permissions, whether it's an add, delete, modification). We just want the name, so we use `--name-only`.

If we wanted absoluted paths, we need to prefix all lines using something like `git rev-parse --show-toplevel`. This gets the absolute path of the repository, without the trailing `/`. So we add that.

```sh
--line-prefix=`git rev-parse --show-toplevel`/
```

Answer (score 0):

I created the following git alias:

```
diffstat = ! "gitdiffstat() {  git diff --stat=$(tput cols) ${1:-master} ; }; gitdiffstat"
```

It reads the column count from the `tput cols` command. It defaults to diffing  against `master`, but you can optionally specify another branch.

```
$ git diffstat
 .gitalias | 2 +-
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+), 1 deletion(-)
```

Answer (score -1):

I found that the behaviour of diff --stat changed somewhere around git 1.7.10 where previously it would shorten file paths to a fixed width by default - it now displays as much as your terminal window will allow. If you are experiencing this problem, make sure you upgrade to 1.8.0 or newer.