# How to generate reports about user contributions?

Tags: git, github, report, reporting

I would like to know how can I create reports.

The first report that I need is the all files who was changed from a specific *user* from a beginning to a end datetime.

The second one, is similar to the first, but I need all messages commits and the files changed from a specific user from a beginning to a end datetime.

How can I perform this?

Example:

## Report 1

**user**

Files changed from *2013-07-03 12:34:45* to *2013-09-16 15:00:37*

```
a.php
b.txt
c.ini
d.rb
... and the other ones
```

## Report 2

**user**

Commits did from *2013-07-03 12:34:45* to *2013-09-16 15:00:37* and the files changed

```
Message commit 1
    e.php
    j.txt

Message commit 2
    ka.rb
    asdf.jsp

... the another ones
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is:

- similar to "[git: show all changed files between two commits](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6827937/6309)",
- but adding date options mentioned in "[List new files added (by anyone) between two dates](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13370644/6309)"
- and with the "`--author`" filter described in  "[How can I view a git log of just one user's commits?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4262780/6309)"

I tested those on the [git repo for git itself](https://github.com/git/git):

- `Report1` would use `git diff`

  ```
  C:\Users\VonC\prog\git\git>
  git diff --author="Junio C Hamano" --name-status --pretty=oneline --abbrev-commit master@{"29 Jun 2013"}..master@{"14 Aug 2013"}
  ```

That is not satisfactory, as it uses the [`rev-parse` syntax](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-rev-parse#_specifying_revisions), which only goes back 90 days.

A more robust way would be to ask [`git rev-list`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-rev-list) to get the right SHA1 for `git diff` to use:
(but that works only in a unix-like bash, not in a DOS shell)

```
    VonC@VonCvb /c/Users/VonC/prog/git/git (master)
    $ git diff --author="Junio C Hamano" --name-status --pretty=oneline --abbrev-commit $(git rev-list -n 1 --before="10 Sep 2012" master) $(git rev-list -n 1 --before="12 Nov 2012" master)
```

- `Report2` would use `git log`:

  ```
  C:\Users\VonC\prog\git\git>
  git log --author="Junio C Hamano" --name-status --pretty=oneline --abbrev-commit --since "10 Sep 2012" --until "12 Nov 2012"
  ```

Comment: Wonderfull script VonC. Thx a lot again^^