# Lines of code not affected by recent commits

Tags: git, diff

How to locate code in a git repository that did **not** change since a given date?
I am trying to report stats (number of files/classes/lines) on a branch in active development, being interested in code that remained unchanged for several weeks. Is there any git command/tool that can help with that?

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing built in "out of the box" to do *exactly* that, but it's not particularly difficult to construct, except for the "class" bit.  The hardest part is deciding exactly what you mean: you are likely to get a lot of quite meaningless statistics even if you think hard about what you would like out of such a tool.

---

First, you will need to pick the *newest* revision that is *not* newer than your "since" date, which is generally a task for `git rev-list` (aka `git log`) with its `--min-age` and `--max-age` options (also known as `--until` and `--since`).

Use these, plus whatever additional options are required (possibly `--first-parent`, depending on merges and desired behavior around them, and other sorting options like `--author-date-order`, plus anything needed to compensate for bad clocks on clients—your git believes "them", whoever "they" are, when they send you a new commit today that is dated either 1975 or 2031, which could skew your statistics).  Decide what behavior you want, then adjust the options to get it.

In any case, the result will be a list of revision IDs in some order (the order depends on what sorting options you gave; the default is "reverse chronological order" by committer timestamp).

Pick the newest one of those, possibly using `-n 1` or `-1` (same thing).  Now you have a starting point: one end of the "what has and has not changed" equation.  The other end is simply the tip of the branch, i.e., whatever `git rev-parse <branchname>` says, although there should be no need to translate from name to raw commit ID, especially if you simply have that branch checked-out.

At this point, the most direct tool is probably `git blame` (which must be run on each file of interest).  Note that it has some (but not all) of the above built in to it: in particular, it can work directly with `--since`, which essentially tells it "use everything from `HEAD` back to, but not before, the `--since` date".  Its output format here should be fairly obvious.  It will not report lines that are deleted from the most-base version it inspects, but those lines are obviously "changed"; and of course it has no idea how to count whatever constitutes a "class" (which will depend on your language of choice: C++ and Python will require very different handling, for instance).

To discover deleted lines and deleted files, it helps to have the raw ID of the original revision: you can then use, e.g., `git diff --stat <original> <latest>` and parse its output (but [beware of truncation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10460154/1256452)).

Comment: Thanks @torek for your help! I managed to checkout two revisions and combined all source files with `find src | grep "\.java$" | xargs cat >>src.txt` for each. Comparing the two text files gave me stats regarding common code (lines). I gave up comparing classes as they are in the range of hundreds, basically all of them modified over the examined period.

Comment: Ah, you had not mentioned Java earlier. That gives you extra headaches since refactoring *requires* renaming files and tends to reduce the reliability of `git diff` or `git blame` in terms of finding moved and/or copied code. Dumping everything into a single file might not be that good either though, as most diff tools do not attempt to find moved code blocks (algorithms that do search for moves tend to run terribly slowly).