# PHP exec output is abbreviate and cut

Tags: php, git, exec

I try to catch the output of git log files

**the shell**

```
/usr/bin/git log --stat --pretty=format:%an*_*%cd*_*%H*_*%s
```

**output**

```
rrr*_*Wed Mar 29 15:03:44 2016 +0800*_*51c32954639dffbdba18050527ca56b0ec243453*_*bug#1395
 mine-web-manage/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/views/organ/courseForm.jsp                                         |  6 +++++-
 mine-web-server/src/main/java/com/mine/web/server/controller/organ/RestPublicOrganTeacherController.java | 53 +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
 2 files changed, 58 insertions(+), 1 deletion(-)
```

but with php exec, the string is cut off

**the code**

```
$cmd = "/usr/bin/git log --stat --pretty=format:%an*_*%cd*_*%H*_*%s";
exec($cmd, $list, $return);
var_dump($list);
```

**output**

```
  string(90) "rrr*_*Wed Mar 29 15:03:44 2016 +0800*_*51c32954639dffbdba18050527ca56b0ec243453*_*bug#1395"
  [18] =>
  string(60) " .../main/webapp/WEB-INF/views/organ/courseForm.jsp |  6 ++-"
  [19] =>
  string(79) " .../organ/RestPublicOrganTeacherController.java    | 53 ++++++++++++++++++++++"
  [20] =>
  string(49) " 2 files changed, 58 insertions(+), 1 deletion(-)"
```

and I tried the following methods, all not work，result all cut off

```
1, $cmd . " 2>&1"
2, $cmd . " > /tmp/cmd.txt"
3, passthru($cmd, $list, $return);
```

i want to get full string in output

Anyone has some idea about what is happening?

Thank you very much in advance for your help.

Comment: @PaulCrovella，is fine，think you

Answer (score 0):

use the code is fine

```
git log  --stat=200 --pretty=format:%an*_*%cd*_*%H*_*%s
```

[show full file path in git log](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10459374/making-git-diff-stat-show-full-file-path)