# What is a reliable way to detect whether a file or directory has changed in the most recent commit?

Tags: git, githooks

I have a web project which I deploy to an `ec2` instance simply by pushing new commits.  I use the `post-recieve` git hook remotely to execute a shell-script which 'deploys' the project by checking it out into a production directory.  The steps are, run `npm install` on the express app, `npm install` on the frontend (a `create-react-app` app), then run `npm run build` (which basically utilizes `web-pack` to build an optimized distribution folder from my node source code).

These steps are expensive and in many cases not needed. E.G. if all I did was update a Node component in `srcs/components/` then `npm run build` should run, but `npm install` on the server and frontend shouldn't.  If all I have done is added a comment to my express app, no scripts should run.

My currently server-side deploy script looks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

GIT_WORK_TREE=/home/ec2-user/absiteProd git checkout -f

### TODO: conditional NPM work

pm2 restart index
```

My question is then how can I use git (or grep, sed, awk, etc..) to reliably tell me when either `/home/ec2-user/absiteProd/frontend/package.json`, 
`/home/ec2-user/absiteProd/server/package.json` or anything in 'home/ec2-user/absiteProd/frontend/sources` has changed?

Currently I'm having some success with:

```
if `git log --stat -n 1` | grep --quite frontend/src/* ; then
   cd home/ec2-user/frontend
   npm run build
fi
```

But since this seems like such a common requirement in app deployment,  I feel like there must be a simpler way?

Comment: I have edited the answer with a possible script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find a similar need in [this thread](http://git.661346.n2.nabble.com/last-commit-in-a-directory-td5957924.html):

> How do I find a last commit for the given directory inside the repository?
>
> I want to avoid rebuilding the specific part of the project if there were no changes in it since the last build, so I need to find the sha of the last time the directory was changed.

You can compare the last commit where an element is modified, using [`git rev-list`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rev-list):

```
git rev-list -1 HEAD -- frontend/package.json
git rev-list -1 HEAD -- absiteProd/server/package.json
git rev-list -1 HEAD -- frontend/src
```

with the current HEAD SHA1 ([`git rev-parse`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rev-parse), the [`--verify`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rev-parse#git-rev-parse---verify) is optional):

```
git rev-parse --verify HEAD
```

---

That is:

```
h=$(git rev-parse --verify HEAD)
b=false
if [[ "$(git rev-list -1 HEAD -- frontend/package.json)" == "${h}" ]]; then b=true; fi
if [[ "$(git rev-list -1 HEAD -- frontend/package.json)" == "${h}" ]]; then b=true; fi
if [[ "$(git rev-list -1 HEAD -- frontend/package.json)" == "${h}" ]]; then b=true; fi
if !b; then exit 0; fi
cd home/ec2-user/frontend
npm run build
```

Comment: @AlexBollbach Yes, that is the idea. I would actually exit if there is a difference. If all three tests don't show any difference, then `npm install /frontend`

Comment: sry i deleted my comment.  i wanted to do some research on your answer first.. I'm trying to understand the output of rev-list.

Comment: @AlexBollbach No problem. I have updated/fixed the script.

Comment: this will take me sometime to grok.. looking at it though, it doesn't seem to allow 3 conditional commands.  `npm install` for frontend/backend and `npm run build`, it would need `a,b,c` booleans, no?

Comment: @AlexBollbach the idea is that, if any of the file has changed in the last commit (HEAD), b is true, meaning you must build.

Comment: ah i see, only if `npm run build` and `npm install` (in frontend, say) both take 10 seconds, I wouldn't want to spend 20 seconds on something that could take 10.

Comment: also would `git rev-list -1 HEAD -- absiteProd/server/package.json` be correct here?  as the checkout-dir is distinct from my repo which is bare.

Comment: @AlexBollbach Yes, `git rev-list` does not nneed a working tree, so it will work.

Answer (score 1):

Git does not *store* directories in any useful way, so you must define what you mean by "anything in" yourself (which has its advantages since you can define what *you* mean rather than getting stuck with someone else's useless-to-you definition, but means you must do more work).

That said, Git stores each *file* as a path name within each commit.  Your deployment script takes some work-tree—in this case, `/home/ec2-user/absiteProd`—from one state to another.  Since it uses `git checkout` to do so, and `git checkout` does nothing special with time stamps, you now have many options with many different low-level details and subsequent consequences.  Here are two obvious-ish and reasonably simple starting points:

- Was `/home/ec2-user/absiteProd` exactly the same as some previous commit?  If so, *which* commit?  (Commits have unique hash IDs and these are generally the things to use in scripts.)  You can then have Git compare the previous commit with the new commit, using `git diff --name-status` for instance.  This is similar to what you are doing now, but better.

  If your deployment script is a post-receive script, you already have both the old and new hash IDs of the reference, which you have read from standard input.  Hence the set of files changed, with their statuses, between those two commits, is:

  ```
   git diff-tree -r --name-status $oldhash $newhash
  ```
- If `git checkout` wrote on any file(s), those files will have "now" as their modify-time time-stamps, since `git checkout` just lets the system's time apply to updated files.  Can you use this?  As long as you never deploy more than twice in a single second, you could combine this with the `make` build-system, which builds files based on time-stamps.

If `make` is suitable here, it is probably the best choice, except for its maximum of one-per-second deployment (or whatever your underlying OS has for time stamp resolution on files).  You can just declare that whatever the output file(s) is/are, they depend on the corresponding input file(s), and give the recipe to build the output(s) from the input(s) and run `make`.

Comment: in your first bullet-point, are you talking about running `git diff ...` in the work-tree?

Comment: No, in the post-receive script itself, before or after running `git checkout`. You can do this at any time since the commits now exist in the repository, and all Git is doing is comparing the commits themselves directly (regardless of what is in any work-tree anywhere).

Comment: i did something similar after asking the question: `if git log --stat -n 1 | grep --quiet src/*; then 
 #run script for src/ change
else
 echo do nothing
fi`

Comment: The defects here are: (1) `git log` compares the tip commit (in this case `HEAD`) to its *immediate parent*, which is not necessarily the commit that you had in this work-tree before (what if someone pushed three commits just now, and the files in question were changed in the first two but not in the third?). (2) `git log --stat` abbreviates path names to fit into 80 columns. You can defeat this (https://stackoverflow.com/q/10459374/1256452) but it's better to just go straight to the plumbing commands. (3) `git log` and other porcelain commands obey user config and are not meant for scripting.