# Make `git stash show`, print full file path

Tags: git

I try to restore single files from a stash, therefor I need the full path of the files. But if I execute `git stash show` then often only a short path is shown.

e.g.

```
$ git stash show
 .idea/deployment.xml                               |   4 +-
 .idea/test.iml                                     |   4 +-
 .idea/workspace.xml                                | 635 +++++++++++++++------
 .../local/Black/NewsletterPopup/Block/Show.php    |  13 +
 .../local/Black/NewsletterPopup/etc/config.xml    |  15 +
 .../frontend/venedor/default/layout/popup.xml      |   9 +
 .../default/template/black/popup/index.phtml      |   1 +
 app/etc/modules/Black_NewsletterPopup.xml         |   9 +
 8 files changed, 505 insertions(+), 185 deletions(-)
```

Is there a way to show the full path?

If I execute `git checkout stash@{0} -- .../local/Black/NewsletterPopup/Block/Show.php`

Then I get `error: pathspec '.../local/Black/NewsletterPopup/Block/Show.php' did not match any file(s) known to git.`

I was already <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> the [documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash) for `path` but nothing relevant found.

Comment: Does `git --no-pager stash show` help?

Comment: Not a full answer, but in some cases you could just `git stash apply` and then reset out the files you _don't_ want to be affected by the stash.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, good idea! +Arkadius, nope, still short paths.

Comment: Is `...` a directory in your repo? I make a test and find there might be a bug if `...` is created as a directory. `git ls-tree -r -t stash@{0}` prints there are two sub-trees `../` and `./` instead of `...`.

Comment: @ElpieKay, No it isn't.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/q/10459374/1256452 (not quite a duplicate since it's about `git diff`, but `git stash show` *runs* `git diff`).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can give `git diff`-type format options to `git stash show`, so

```
git stash show --name-only
```

would be one way.

Comment: Note that `git stash show` runs `git diff --stat`, so you also have the width options from `git diff` available.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a direct answer to your question, but you could just `git stash apply` and then reset out the files you don't want to be affected by the stash.  Something like this:

```
git stash apply
```

and then

```
git checkout -- file1.ext
```

and so on, for each file which you *don't* want to be affected by the stash.

The answer given by @Mark seems to work.  But let's say you had a stash with 15 files, and you wanted the changes from 14 of those 15 files.  Then it might be more expedient to just apply the full stash and rollback one file than to manually apply 14 files.

Comment: So the `--` is removing the file?

Comment: @Black No, this is just telling Git to replace the file with its current version at the HEAD of the branch, _before_ you applied the stash.