# Git diff -name-only with full file path

Tags: git

currently using:

```
git diff -name-status
```

Now this will only give me the following output:

README.md 
created.txt 
test.txt

However I am looking for something more like this:

/User/github/README.md 
/User/github/created.txt 
/User/github/test.txt

Does anyone know if something like this is possible?

To clarify: the comment from the linked post states: 
All output will return paths relative to git rev-parse --show-toplevel
this is exactly the issue as I would want the path prior to the top level to be included.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Making git diff --stat show full file path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10459374/making-git-diff-stat-show-full-file-path)

Comment: if you try to run the answers on that page the output is not what i am explaining. I am looking for system file paths outside of the git folders, and that answer only seems to explain file paths inside the git folder.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just add the top level yourself:

```
git rev-parse --show-toplevel
```

prints the path to the Git repository.

Feed the diff `--name-only` output through, e.g., `sed -e "s,^,$path,"` (assuming no commas in your path name):

```
git-diff-with-abs-path() {
    local path

    path=$(git rev-parse --show-toplevel) &&
    git diff --name-only "$@" | sed "s,^,$path/,"
}
```

Edit #2: for `--name-status`, the name comes after a literal tab, so:

```
git-diff-with-abs-path() {
    local path tab=$'\t'

    path=$(git rev-parse --show-toplevel) &&
    git diff --name-status "$@" | sed "s,$tab,$tab$path/,"
}
```

Fancy this up a bit and you can make it pick `--name-only` or `--name-status` out of the `$@` part and compute the correct sed expression, rather than hardcoding `--name-only` or `--name-status`.

Comment: One thing this does not do though is include the added modified deleted tag (which does show in name status) I guess i can append it to the back of the command somehow. but if there was a way to do something like:
'
A  /User/github/README.md 
M /User/github/Test.txt
'
That would be more ideal

Comment: True, this is for `--name-only`. To handle `--name-status`, use a literal tab instead. I'll edit that into the answer.

Answer (score 17):

Building on torek's answer, I was able to achieve this in one line using the `--line-prefix` flag:

```
git diff --name-only --line-prefix=`git rev-parse --show-toplevel`/ HEAD release
```

Comment: why not this?  `git diff --name-only --line-prefix="${PWD}/" HEAD master`

Comment: The rev-parse answer worked well for me. PWD works if you are currently at the repo root.

Comment: @Gi0rgi0s PWD is the current directory of the shell and as such is much less reliable

Comment: While the accepted answer works, I believe this to be the best answer in the spirit of using the `git` tool to it's fullest.