# git show truncates output only when piped

Tags: bash, git, git-show

If I execute `git show f12345a --stat` I get the following output:

```
commit f12345a
Author: This Guy <this.guy@email.com>
Date:   Mon Jul 1 14:00:59 2019 -0500

    A commit

 hola/mundo/hola/mundo/hola/mundo/hola/mundo/hola/mundo/hola/mundo/imaginary-very-long-file-name.txt | 2 +-
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+), 1 deletion(-)
```

But if instead I execute `git show f12345a --stat | grep -E "*"` (basically echoing everything) I get:

```
commit f12345a
Author: This Guy <this.guy@email.com>
Date:   Mon Jul 1 14:00:59 2019 -0500

    A commit

 .../hola/mundo/hola/mundo/hola/mundo/imaginary-very-long-file-name.txt  | 2 +-
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+), 1 deletion(-)
```

so the question itself is why is my file name getting truncated? (how can I avoid it)?

This truncate is also applied when performing `git show f12345a --stat > exit.txt`, when I see the file contents the file name is trucated

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/10459374/1256452

Comment: Good thing I (thought I) search... dang it, I swear I spent a good 20 min trying to find that and nothing pop up; guess searches having "git" on them a lot of pollution

Comment: It's not quite the same as your situation and Git has changed a lot since 2012, but some of this stuff still applies. I didn't have time to write up a real answer.

Comment: in deed, but adding `--stat=150` (or a value long enough for your file paths) fixes the issue