# what do 3 leading dots (...) in git diff --stat output stand for

Tags: git, git-diff

I have a bit of a problem understanding this git diff output.

I compare to branches

```
$ git diff --stat f43003..860d281
 subdir/ansible.cfg                                  |  16 +
 subdir/defaults_postgres.yml                        |  43 ++
 .../postgres_install/defaults_postgres.yml          |  43 ++
```

the first 2 lines are clear. 2 Changed files inside `subdir`. I can not make sense of the third line though  `.../postgres_install/defaults_postgres.yml`. Concrete ... what are the 3 dots pointing at?

practically the entire `subdir` had been added in the new commit and this file `defaults_postgres.yml` exists in to location inside `subdir`.

I am aware that this needs to be cleaned up yet, but that is not the point. What ist the logic of that leading '...'? Is it just saving real estate on the screen because the folder structure may be going too deep?

Comment: https://git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions#_dotted_range_notations

Comment: @ElpieKay: but this `...` is not a three-dot dotted range, it's just an abbreviated pathname.

Comment: @torek sorry, I made a mistake.

Comment: @ElpieKay: it happens :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I am aware that this needs to be cleaned up yet, but that is not the point. What is the logic of that leading '...'? Is it just saving real estate on the screen because the folder structure may be going too deep?

Yes: it's literally that.  The `git diff --stat` output has a set of widths it should not exceed, and if the path name part would push the width too high, Git will trim off some off and replace the trimmed part with the `...`.

To raise the limits, do so explicitly or implicitly; see [Making git diff --stat show full file path](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10459374/1256452).