# How to get the terminal result into a file with full file name in linux

Tags: git, command-line

I'm trying to write how many lines of code difference are there between 2 git branches. So i ran the git command for the difference, on **terminal**, where it output the file location along with the number of different lines between two branches.

Although, i know the command to write the terminal output into a file. I've used the below mentioned command to write the terminal output into a file **'code_mismatch.txt'**:

`git diff --compact-summary --ignore-space-change remotes/dev_admin/master origin/master &> code_mismatch.txt`

**A glance on the code_mismatch.txt file:**

```
 application/models/admin/Template_model.php        |    97 +-
 application/models/admin/Ticket_model.php          |    75 +-
 .../models/admin/Tickets_v2/Channel_model.php      |    10 +-
 .../models/admin/Tickets_v2/Superadminmodel.php    |    30 +-
 .../models/admin/Tickets_v2/Template_model.php     |    26 +-
 .../models/admin/Tickets_v2/Ticket_model.php       |     4 +-
 .../merchant/dashboard/ticket_destinations.php     |    16 +-
 .../ticket_list.php (gone)                         |    94 -
 application/views/activity_overview.php            |     2 +-
 application/views/admin/channel.php                |    15 +-
 .../views/admin/company/companysettings_v1.php     |    57 +-
```

But the problem i'm facing is, if the file location written inside the 'code_mismatch.txt' file is a bit long, then it replaces the starting part of the file location with **dots** like this **'...'**.

If i try to run the same command without writing the output into code_mismatch.txt file then on the terminal i'm getting full location of the file.

`git diff --compact-summary --ignore-space-change remotes/dev_admin/master origin/master`

**A glance on terminal output:**

```
 application/models/admin/Template_model.php                                                    |    97 +-
 application/models/admin/Ticket_model.php                                                      |    75 +-
 application/models/admin/Tickets_v2/Channel_model.php                                          |    10 +-
 application/models/admin/Tickets_v2/Superadminmodel.php                                        |    30 +-
 application/models/admin/Tickets_v2/Template_model.php                                         |    26 +-
 application/models/admin/Tickets_v2/Ticket_model.php                                           |     4 +-
 application/views/V1/codes/merchant/dashboard/ticket_destinations.php                          |    16 +-
 application/views/V1/ticket_destinations_list/ticket_list.php (gone)                           |    94 -
 application/views/activity_overview.php                                                        |     2 +-
 application/views/admin/channel.php                                                            |    15 +-
 application/views/admin/company/companysettings_v1.php                                         |    57 +-
 application/views/admin/company/create_new_company.php                                         |   456 ++-
```

Is there a way i can write my file same as the terminal output..??

Thanks!

Comment: Does it work if you add `--stat=0`?

Comment: When i added --stat=0 then even in the terminal i'm getting the result same as the result wrote in the file

Comment: What about `--stat=10000` ? https://stackoverflow.com/a/10460154/7976758

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use the convenience commands, the so-called "porcelain", for scripting. Use the core commands, the ones the convenience commands are built on.

```
git diff-tree --ignore-space-change --numstat remotes/dev_admin/master origin/master
```

will produce output with all the tradeoffs between readability by computers and humans decided in the computer's favor rather than the other way round.