# How do I show git files which were deleted several commits ago

Tags: git

I have deleted a file several commits ago and now I need part of it.
How to show it so I can copy paste?

I've tried this:

```
git show HEAD~2 -- path/to/file
```

But I get no output at all.
Autocompletion doesn't work with deleted files so I am not 100% sure about file name, but I am 99% sure.

Comment: Are you using Linux or Windows ? If windows how you are accessing git (through UI or command) ? If command - see my answer below

Comment: Please select correct answer. It will be helpful for others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`git cat-file -p HEAD~2:path/to/file`

Answer (score 4):

List all changed files between two commits.

```
 git diff --name-only START_COMMIT..END_COMMIT
```

Using --name-status will also show the changes like added, deleted, Modified along with file

```
git diff --name-status START_COMMIT..END_COMMIT
```

Answer (score 1):

You can checkout the commit where you deleted it (`git checkout "old-commit-hash"`), copy the files you need and and checkout your current data again (`git commit "current-commit-hash"`).

The hashes can be looked up with: `git log`

Comment: Then I'd need to stash changes I've made first? Can you do the full command list?

Comment: You can either stash them with `git stash` or commit them already (not push).
After you commited the changes, you can use `git commit --amend` to amend new changes to your commit.

Comment: The complete change would then be:
1) `git add "changed files"`
2) `git commit`
3) `git log` -> to find out the commit where the files are deleted and your current one
4) `git checkout "old-commit-hash"`
5) copy your fies you need
6) `git checkout "current-commit-hash"`
7) make changes and amend them to your current commit with `git add files`, `git commit --amend`

Answer (score 1):

You can find out a name of your deleted file using command `git whatchanged`. It shows a list of files that was modified by previous commits. Deleted files are marked with letter D. After you recognize the filename, to restore it, type `git checkout <hash_id>~ -- <filename>`, where `<hash_id>` means a hash of a commit in which you deleted the file with specified  `<filename>`.

If you want to look at the file only, type `git show <hash_id> -- <filename>`. This command prints changes (including deleting) of the file made by the specified commit.

Comment: Thanks, didn't know about `git whatchanged`. Is `~` a typo in `git checkout <hash_id>~ -- <filename>`? Can I just show the file without checking it out? Not sure why `git show hashid -- path/to/file` shows diff instead of full file.

Comment: The tilde is needed to restore the file. The tilde after a commit hash refers to the previous commit in which that file still was. But if your goal is only to look at the file, of course, `show` command is enough. I supplemented the answer, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is :

1. You removed a file
2. Then committed
3. Lot's of commits happened
4. Now need information of that file.

If this is the case, what you have done is correct. But something more to achieve it.

1. `git log --pretty=format:"%h - %an, %ad --> %s" --date=iso`
   This will give you commits with date in readable format.
   Let there are 100 commits and your commit date is around 30th from HEAD (then take some 'last 40' commits)
2. `git log --pretty=format:"%h - %an, %ad --> %s" --date=iso | head -40 | awk '{print $1}'`
   If this gives 40 commits as output, do the following.
3. `while read commit ; do echo -e "\n\nFile committed in $commit are : " ; git show --pretty="format:" --name-only $commit ;  done< <(git log --pretty=format:"%h - %an, %ad --> %s" --date=iso | head -40 | awk '{print $1}')`
4. Then take the commit ID with your file.
5. And then you can go for your command.

Answer (score 0):

**Using gitk.**

One simple approach, if you happen to use the gitk gui, just simple run `gitk` in your terminal and go through the git tree list where you can the deleted files.

---

**Using CLI way:**

```
git log --your_file_path
```

or

```
git log --full-history -- your_file_path
```

If you just want to see the deleted file from the tree, [Check this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19727752/7640269).

Answer (score 0):

This will show you last change on particular file:

```
git log -1 -p -- <file_path>
```

However, this sometimes is not very handy, since you will see the changes, but copy-paste process might be tricky due to leading `-` in front of every change line.

If you want to restore the file so that you can easily copy-paste from it:

- Get SHA of the commit where you have deleted the file:

  ```
  git rev-list -n 1 HEAD -- <file_path>
  ```
- Checkout the file at the commit before, using the caret (`^`) symbol:

  ```
  git checkout <SHA>^ -- <file_path>
  ```